# AWS Lambda can't define config

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently running some code which works using the amazon sdk, but i am using my Key to authenticate to Refer:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "ID",
  secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
});
```

When i upload it to the lambda, i dont want it to be needed to be used with any AWS code, is it possible?
on every GET that i use AWS to do a function, i get a

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
>
> Method completed with status: 502

And again on my client it works i just took off the AWS.config, because it is on the AWS platform i think it needs to without without it..
Am i mistaken? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After digging alot, I found out u dont need to configure the api, u just need to specify correct permission to the role u currently use with the Lambda function.